How to ensure that SSH drops the connection after 8 hours of no typing?
On our Debian 12 servers, I want to ensure that any SSH connections times out and disconnects after 8 hours of no typing. This was recommended by our security consultant, as some exploits can take advantage of connections that happen to left open for days or even months. Better to "Close the door after you have finished maintenance".
I executed these steps:
# Log in as root then:
sudo vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
# Use / to search for and change:
ClientAliveInterval=3600
ClientAliveCountMax=8
# Second parameter is number of hours before connection times out and drops.

# Then test config:
sudo sshd -t
# Restart
sudo systemctl restart sshd

However, the tests failed. When I temporarily set ClientAliveInterval=120 and ClientAliveCountMax=2 and restarted the sshd daemon, I would expect the connection to drop after 4 minutes of no typing. However, it did not.
Any ideas?

OpenSSH sshd_config
Correct configuration keywords since OpenSSH 9.2 (Debian 12)
The OpenSSH 9.2 (Feb 2, 2023) introduced new features for inactive sessions.


sshd(8): add support for channel inactivity timeouts via a new
sshd_config(5) ChannelTimeout directive. This allows channels that
have not seen traffic in a configurable interval to be
automatically closed. Different timeouts may be applied to session,
X11, agent and TCP forwarding channels.

sshd(8): add a sshd_config UnusedConnectionTimeout option to
terminate client connections that have no open channels for a
length of time. This complements the ChannelTimeout option above.



For the eight hours in this question, e.g.,
ChannelTimeout *=8h
UnusedConnectionTimeout 1m

Where:

The *=8h monitors all channels separately. If you want activity on any channel to reset the timeout, use the special keyword global=8h.
The UnusedConnectionTimeout is set to one minute in order to terminate the connection shortly after the last channel has been closed.

For OpenSSH < 9.2 that has to be done by other means.
The used configuration keywords are for unresponsive sessions
The ClientAliveInterval does not monitor for inactivity but whether the client is still responsive.

Sets a timeout interval in seconds after which if no data has been received from the client, sshd(8) will send a message through the encrypted channel to request a response from the client. The default is 0, indicating that these messages will not be sent to the client.

The documentation for ClientAliveCountMax may help in understanding this:

If ClientAliveInterval is set to 15, and ClientAliveCountMax is left at the default, unresponsive SSH clients will be disconnected after approximately 45 seconds. Setting a zero ClientAliveCountMax disables connection termination.

 A historical note: Before OpenSSH 8.2 (Feb 14, 2020) the ClientAliveCountMax worked differently with 0, having the side effect that it could have been used for terminating idle connections. From the changelog:

Bugfixes

sshd(8): make ClientAliveCountMax=0 have sensible semantics: it
will now disable connection killing entirely rather than the
current behaviour of instantly killing the connection after the
first liveness test regardless of success. bz2627


⚠️ Yet, this misleading instruction has been repeated all over the Internet:

Geeks for Geeks: Disconnecting Inactive SSH Connections in Linux
Vivek Gite on nixCraft: Linux / UNIX Automatically Logout BASH / TCSH / SSH Users After a Period of Inactivity
Hayden James on Linuxblog.io: How to Kill Inactive SSH Sessions
KGIII on Linux Tips: Disable Inactive SSH Sessions
Aaron Kili on Techmint: How to Disconnect Inactive or Idle SSH Connections in Linux
Satish Kumar on Tutorials Point: How to Disconnect Inactive or Idle SSH Connections in Linux?

Of these, only Gite had the ClientAliveCountMax=0 that could have worked before 2020, but does this count? After all, the article was likely written in 2021... Makes me wonder does anyone read the documentation or are they busy copy-pasting other's blog posts. ‍♂️
In-depth discussion on alternatives
Scripting – be careful you detect inactivity correctly
Hayden James gives an example for Automating the Process with a script. However, using that script is dangerous as it could kill SSH sessions that are in active use. The script gets the "idle time" from ps -eo pid,etimes,comm where the etimes does not show the idle time of the process but the total time it has been running. From ps(1):

STANDARD FORMAT SPECIFIERS



CODE
HEADER
DESCRIPTION




etimes
ELAPSED
elapsed time since the process was started, in seconds.




Satish Kumar suggests using who for list of active users and the fifth column of w -h for detecting inactivity. However, this script also has some flaws:

The fifth column does not contain the seconds as an integer, but a string value like 2.00s, 7:51m or 5days. The [[ "$idle" -gt "1800" ]]; does not parse that correctly.
If the comparison was possible, the script would kill all processes of the user...

...in case the users has not typed anything in any of the sessions.
...including terminal multiplexers (screen, tmux) and other processes that are intended to live outside an active SSH session.



The detection of the inactivity should be way more precise, as well as the selection of the process to be killed.
This approach could work:

Take the sessions directly from the second column of who.
Use stat to get the last access time of the TTY device (see answer from Celada).
who -s | awk '{ print $2 }' | (cd /dev && xargs stat -c '%n %U %X')

That can be directly converted to age in seconds:
who -s | awk '{ print $2 }' | (cd /dev && xargs stat -c '%n %U %X') \
  | awk '{ print $1"\t"$2"\t"'"$(date +%s)"'-$3 }'


Use pgrep to find sshd processes for the TTYs, or pkill to kill them.
user=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $1}')
tty=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $2}')
age=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $3}')
pgrep -f "sshd: ${user}@${tty}"



All put together (more complete find-inactive-ssh-sessions.sh in oh2fih/Misc-Scripts):
#!/bin/bash
MAX_IDLE=28800  # default 8 hours
KILL=0          # set 1 to kill instead of list

# Get TTYs with the seconds since the last access time
TTYS=$(
  who -s \
    | awk '{ print $2 }' \
    | grep -ve "^:"
  )
if [ "$TTYS" = "" ]; then
  exit 0
fi

TTY_AGES=$(
  echo "$TTYS" \
    | (cd /dev && xargs stat -c '%U %n %X') \
    | awk '{ print $1"\t"$2"\t"'"$(date +%s)"'-$3 }'
  )

# Get sshd processes of the TTYs; list or kill
while IFS= read -r line ; do 
  user=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1'})
  tty=$(echo $line | awk '{print $2'})
  age=$(echo $line | awk '{print $3'})
  if (( $age > $MAX_IDLE )); then
    if (( KILL == 1 )); then
      pkill -f "sshd: ${user}@${tty}"
    else
      pgrep -f -a "sshd: ${user}@${tty}"
    fi
  fi
done <<< "$TTY_AGES"

Built-in features in shells
As Vivek Gite mentions, shells have features for automatically logging the user out after a period of inactivity. These might work if there is no need to enforce the logout, as the user is able to change these settings.

TMOUT environment variable for bash, zsh & ksh.
export TMOUT=28800


autologout setting in tcsh & csh.
set -r autologout 28800



If you configure these through, e.g., /etc/profile.d/, they affect all sessions. However, you could use features in sshd_config to configure them, too: SetEnv & ForceCommand. E.g.,
SetEnv TMOUT=28800

Match Group cshusers
    ForceCommand set -r autologout 28800

Where does the recommendation come from?
The advice is likely based on, e.g., NIST 800-171 Revision 2:

3.1.11 Terminate (automatically) a user session after a defined condition.
DISCUSSION
This requirement addresses the termination of user-initiated logical sessions in contrast to the
termination of network connections that are associated with communications sessions (i.e.,
disconnecting from the network). A logical session (for local, network, and remote access) is
initiated whenever a user (or process acting on behalf of a user) accesses an organizational system.
Such user sessions can be terminated (and thus terminate user access) without terminating
network sessions. Session termination terminates all processes associated with a user’s logical
session except those processes that are specifically created by the user (i.e., session owner) to
continue after the session is terminated. Conditions or trigger events requiring automatic session
termination can include organization-defined periods of user inactivity, targeted responses to
certain types of incidents, and time-of-day restrictions on system use.

You should decide which one is more important for you: preventing someone from using the connection without permission or the reliability of management connections. Could the unauthorized use be prevented by other means? E.g., could the SSH connections be limited only to company computers, and could the company computers be forced to be locked on inactivity?

Absolutely brilliant answer. I was under the mistaken impression that I could stop typing and the connection would drop after inactivity. Your post corrects this.

I found out that ClientAliveCountMax=0 actually worked before OpenSSH 8.2 (Feb 2020), but only one of the articles had it right, and even that one was written after the bug causing this "feature" as a side effect was fixed. This anecdote is added to my answer as a historical note.

@Contango: I've found the configuration keywords you need, if you are using Debian 12. The current oldstable Debian 11 has OpenSSH 8.4 that did not yet support those keywords.

This is a great answer. I think both groups of settings are valid in their own way. ChannelTimeout seems to focus only on inactivity (probably due to PCI pests) and ClientAliveInterval would be more user friendly from firewall timeouts. RDP does something similar with keep alive. Not having a keepalive on a connection would result in a terminated network connection, due to firewalls usually have short timeouts.

@EsaJokinen We are using Debian 12 and ChannelTimeout looks like t does exactly what we need. Thanks again, wish I could upvote you more.
